# I don't understand this code - Python exercise odd or even

Tags: python

I'm a beginner coder and I'm studying Python. I'm doing some exercise to improve my code.
I don't understand the logic that there is behind in these codes.

The code above is my code (forgive me if it is not performing with the standards that are around).

And this is the solution but again I don't understand why they put it mod > 0

```
#input number and print
number = int(input ('Insert number:'))
print(number)
if (number % 2):
 print('Odd')
else:
 print('Even')
```

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
mod = num % 2
if mod > 0:
    print("You picked an odd number.")
else:
    print("You picked an even number.")
```

I ask if there is someone that explain me these codes and if there is a way to make my code cleaner.

Comment: Both solutions are okay, since `0` is interpreted as `False`.

Comment: `%` is the modulo (remainder) operator. Divide a number by 2 and the remainder will be 1 for odd numbers or 0 for even numbers.

Answer (score 2):

An odd number is equal to 1 modulo 2.

In this code, `mod` is either equal to `0` or `1` (because modulo `2` implies it). Therefore, the condition `mod>0` is equivalent to `mod==1`, which is exactly what you are looking for if you want to know if the number is odd.

Obviously, as a consequence, if `mod==0`, the number is even

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator or `%` gives the remainder when the left number is divided by the right number.

So `10 % 2` would be `0` as there is no remainder in this division.

`10 % 3` would be `1` as 3 goes into 10 3 times with 1 left over.

The bottom code is checking that the remainder is greater than 0, as when it 0 there is no remained so the number must be even.